# Kernel and normal process

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel

I know a process has its own address space ranging from 0x0 to 0xffffffff (please correct if I'm wrong). 
Is Linux kernel a special process with its own address space too?
How does CPU switch if CPU encounter a call from process A to a function whose codes reside in kernel address space?

Comment: 0x10000 to 0xBFFFFFFF if using 32-bit Linux.  http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory

Answer (score 2):

The kernel doesn't really behave like a process at all. It doesn't get scheduled, it either runs on behalf of a process (so called process-context or user-context), or runs as a result of an interrupt or exception (so called interrupt-context).

That said, the Linux kernel spawns kernel threads to perform some tasks, or to avoid running something on interrupt context for too long (that is what the 'ksoftirqd' thread does, avoiding excessive latencies that could lead e.g: to dropped audio,...).

You can see the kernel threads on the output of the ps command. They are easily identified: their name is between brackets. Some of them run one instance per CPU, the CPU is identified with a number after a slash, so [ksoftirqd/0] is the instance of ksoftirqd on CPU 0.

Process just mean a bit of executing code. Yeah, the kernel executes before init (and the boot loader before that even). But a 'process' has a specific definition:

- Runs in user space
- Runs with a process ID
- Many interactions need to go through the kernel
- All resources need to come from kernel
- Needs to be scheduled by kernel

So, once the kernel initializes, it runs init process, which then spawns whatever other processes it's configuration says to.

And when a process calls a function that is part of kernel code, the function executes as part of process only or else part of kernel itself act on behalf of this process.